# How to get the file object instead of the file path with useRef in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

How can I get the actual file instead of just the file path using refs?

`props.onAdd(enteredFormData)`, in the parent component, I just console logged the enteredFormData, it returns the file path, not the actual file.

```
export default function Form(props) {
  const classNameRef = useRef()
  const classImageRef = useRef()

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const enteredClassName = classNameRef.current.value
    const enteredClassImage = classImageRef.current.value

    const enteredFormData = {
      title: enteredClassName,
      image: enteredClassImage
    }

    props.onAdd(enteredFormData)  // in the parent component, I just console logged the 
                                  // enteredFormData, it returns the file path, not the actual 
                                  // file
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Class Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Class Name"
            name="title"
            ref={classNameRef}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Image</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            placeholder="Image"
            name="classImageURL"
            ref={classImageRef}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file to an input is stored in `classImageRef.current.files` which is an array. If you are uploading a single image, you can access it by `classImageRef.current.files[0]`.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications